# how to write a mysql_database.property file in classpath using netbeans and java!!! not to able to access it

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

```
test_database.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_database
test_database.jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
test_database.jdbc.username = username
test_database.jdbc.password = password

new > other > other >  Properties file
```

so plz can anyone teach me how to write the poperties file in correct classpath and access them...

as i wrote the above in my property file its not working... Actually i dont how to place the properties file in classpath

Thanks for ur time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the properties file at the root folder of your source/class files. So if you have a class

```
com.example.MyClass
```

then the file structure could be like that:

```
./com/example/MyClass.class
./db.properties
```

Now `db.properties` is definitly on the classpath.